# Преобразовать object[] в string[]

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, объекты

Собственно вопрос в шапке.

Есть некий массив `object[]` состоящий из `Guid`'ников, нужно этот массив преобразовать в `string[]`.

Пробовал так:

```
var strings = objects as string[];
```

Но получил `null`.

Есть какой-то способ избежать цикла и скастить всё это сразу?

Comment: LINQ-ом *(8 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor Точно, линк... С утра что-то думается плохо)

Comment: @dmepty, `LINQ` это тот же цикл, который вынесли в функцию.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Метод: [`Array.ConvertAll`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_ConvertAll__2___0___System_Converter___0___1__) - преобразует массив одного типа в массив другого типа.

### Вариант #1

```
object[] inputArray = new object[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };
string[] resultArray = Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, x => x?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
```

Ссылка на источник: [Converting a Object[] array to an string[] array in C# (ConvertAll method)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319009/5275890)

---

### Вариант #2

```
string ConvertObjectToString(object obj)
{
    return obj?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}

object[] input = new object[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };
string[] result = Array.ConvertAll<object, string>(input, ConvertObjectToString);
```

Ссылка на источник: [Converting a Object[] array to an string[] array in C# (Array.ConvertAll Method)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15318966/5275890)

Answer (score 5):

```
var strings = objects.Select(x => x?.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант №1**

```
    var objects = new Object[3] { Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D") };
    var strings = objects.Cast<String>();
```

**Вариант №2**

```
    var MyObjects = new Object[3] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };
    var MyStrings = MyObjects.Cast<Object, String>();

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TInput, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TInput> source)
    {
        return source.CastIterator<TInput, TResult>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TInput, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TInput> source)
    {
        return source.ExpressionToFunc<TInput, TResult>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> ExpressionToFunc<TInput, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TInput> source)
    {
        foreach (var obj in source)
        {
            var exp = Expression.Constant(obj.ToString());
            var type = Expression.TypeAs(exp, typeof(TResult));
            var compile = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult>>(type).Compile();
            yield return compile();
        }
    }
```

Comment: В вопросе сказано, что в массиве GUID'ы. Cast приведёт к исключению.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, это зависит как хранить GUID'ы в массиве Object